# Arduino, receive byte array via bluetooth from Xamarin

Tags: android, c, xamarin, bluetooth, arduino

I created Xamarin Android app to connect via bluetooth with arduino and modula HC-06. It works fine, but now I want to send data to arduino. I'm sending string from Android using:

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
```

My problem is reciving the data on Arduino side. Should I encode byte array, ASCII or how to read it to have a string message on Arduino ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `ASCII == char` and `Unicode == wchar_t`. Do keep in mind that `GetBytes` does not append a `'\0'` or `L'\0'` character. If you encode as Unicode then `buffer.Length` does not necessarily equal to `msg.Length`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
How do I implement ASCII == char and 'Unicode == wchar_t' in Arduino exactly?

Comment: As with any string handling. Dynamically allocate using `malloc`. Also I believe Arduino supports C++ (or some form of C++), so you could also use the `new[]` operator or even better `std::string` (or `std::wstring`). Again, do keep in mind that no null character is appended to `buffer`

Comment: Arduino unfortunately does not support C++. Also, i'm not sure wchar_t is available.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does support C++ (in a skeleton form), see [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=2249.0). However that is not the point, neither is `wchar_t`. You can just use `malloc` and `char` instead.